# AJAX check page return every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to make a simple AJAX script but I don't know how to do that :
Every 5 minutes, the scripts check if the page "req.php?online_mode" returns the text "true" or "false". If it returns "true", it'll do anything, but if it returns "false", it will show a Javascript alert().
Any help please ? Sorry for bad english,
**Cheers, MrZ**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera fácil y rápida, así:

```
function ajaxCheck(url, minutes, text){
   if(text == "false") return alert("Finalize!");

   setTimeout(function(){
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
         xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && ajaxCheck(url, minutes, xhr.responseText)
      };
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.send()
   }, 60*1000*minutes)
}

ajaxCheck("req.php?online_mode", 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
make_call = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", 
                success: function(result){
                    if (result == true) {
                        make_call();
                    } else {
                        alert("!!!");
                    }
            }});
    }, 300000);
}
```

---

If you want to use native Javasript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'demo_test.text', true);
request.onload = function() {
    make_call();
};
request.send();
```

Comment: The OP did not specifically request or tag jQuery.  Usually that means answers should not use jQuery.